# npm can't find package.json

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to install the dependencies of some example: npm's `express 2.5.8` that I've downloaded, but all of the apps throw the same error:

```
c:\node\stylus>npm install -d
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@1.1.1
npm info using node@v0.6.11
npm ERR! Couldn't read dependencies.

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\node\stylus\package.json'
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-d"
npm ERR! cwd c:\node\stylus
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.11
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.1
npm ERR! path c:\node\stylus\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\node\stylus\package.json'

npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\node\stylus\npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

The blockage appears to be:

> no such file or directory 'c:\node\stylus\package.json

Did I miss a step that creates the `package.json` ?

I'm running:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- npm 1.1.1
- node 6.11
- express 2.5.8

Comment: How did you download the packages? Can you install them the usual way (i.e. with `npm install <package>`?

Comment: I haven't tried that, because I don't know exactly which packages are used in the apps. How can I find this out so I can try installing them manually?

Comment: `npm view <package>` will show you the `package.json` along with the dependencies. Also, `npm help` is your friend.

Comment: I've checked out the package file with `npm view package` but I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/AwGHu.gif. I'm trying to get some of these to work: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/2.x/examples

Comment: Hmmm... `<package>` was meant as an example. Try e.g. `npm view stylus`.

Comment: Look at this error it's throwing regarding package.json module is deprecated: https://gist.github.com/1933333

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8313/discussion-between-linus-g-thiel-and-imjp)

Comment: use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224025/npm-behind-a-proxy-with-the-character-in-my-password/50214574#50214574).
it worked for me.

Comment: what i did i i upgrade pnpm `pnpm add -g pnpm` then `pnpm i`

Answer (score 147, accepted):

In your project's folder, you need to initialize the `package.json` file by running the following in the terminal:

```
npm init
```

After that, you should be able to install any packages as you would expect, like express:

```
npm install express
```

Shout out to [Deepali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687665/719987).

Comment: and where is express if I previously installed with "npm install -g express" ?

Comment: You need to execute "npm install -g express-generator" with > Express 4.0.0. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002448/express-command-not-found , after that the express command can be executed

Comment: UBUNTU console suggested `sudo apt install node-express-generator` ... So, what the best, `apt install`  or `npm install`?

Answer (score 211):

I think, `npm init` will create your missing `package.json` file. It works for me for the same case.

Answer (score 89):

I'll be brief but deadly. :) install -d will not work for you. It's simple. Try

```
$ npm install -g express
```

Comment: Not worked, need `sudo npm install -g express` ... Is correct?

Comment: > "the -g flag is a shorthand for the global configuration which sets the package install location to the folder where you installed NodeJS."

Answer (score 68):

Follwing the below steps you well get **package.json** file.

```
npm --version
npm install express
npm init -y
```

Answer (score 19):

If Googling **"no such file or directory package.json"** sent you here, then you might be using a very old version of Node.js

The following page has good instructions of how to easily install the latest stable on many Operating systems and distros:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: Was using `node --version` 0.10.31 and was having this issue. Downgraded to 0.10.29 and it still wasn't resolved. It seems to be an issue with the Windows installer as they've also ceased creating the `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder.

Comment: I got the "no such file or directory package.json" error trying to run 'npm install' on the Angular.js tutorial and ended up here. It wasn't obvious in the instructions that you need to cd into the checked out code for the tutorial - in this case the package.json is in the dir you cloned from git in the prior step (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Comment: @KevinHooke's solution is the answer for this problem. Running npm -install from the cloned application directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Beginners usually try the npm command from random locations.
After downloading or creating a project, you have to go into project folder. Inside this folder is the file package.json.

```
cd <path_to_project>
npm install
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the command in win7/win8/win10 (CD) for moving folders:

1. Enter your projects folder
2. Run: `npm install -d`

Answer (score 4):

try re-install Node.js

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -`

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

and update npm

```
curl -L https://npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 3):

Node comes with npm installed so you should have a version of npm. However, npm gets updated more frequently than Node does, so you'll want to make sure it's the latest version.

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

Test:

```
npm -v //The version should be higher than 2.1.8
```

After this you should be able to run:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

I found myself here trying to resolve the same error message:

```
npm ERR! message ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\<some_folder>\package.json'
```

The error could be due to two reasons:

1. You do not have the package.json
2. You have the `package.json`, but you are running `npm start` in the wrong folder

To troubleshoot the first cause, you need to create a package.json using:

```
npm init
```

To fix the second cause, make sure the folder you are running the `npm start` command is the same folder as the `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

It may be very evident,
but try to launch `CMD` (for Windows) **from the project folder**, 
where your *package.json* file is located.

Do not launch `CMD` from System or from "Search bar" in Win or
move to your project folder with help of `cd` command and then launch `npm start`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with npm. The problem was that I had the project inside two folders of the same name. I resolved it by renaming one of the folders to something else (outer folder recommended).

Answer (score 2):

It by itself says that `package.json` is not available in your project.
So, to create `package.json`, use the following steps:

1. open command prompt on your project directory
2. `npm init` (it will ask you to enter lots of entries like name, version, desc, etc., enter some random values and click enter).
3. type `yes` and click enter

Now try again.

Answer (score 2):

Go inside the project folder and check whether the package.json file does exist.

If you are creating the project using Visual Studio Angular project, make sure you run this command inside the ClientApp Folder. there is a good chance, you could be looking for project.json file outside the ClientApp folder.

Comment: This just happened to me. I wanted to answer but since you already have, accept my upvote :p

Answer (score 2):

if the package.json file in the project directory is missing then you can create it by 
**[npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file)**.

if the  package.json file is already created in the project directory then there is a possibility that you are not running your project from the right path.
Use **[cd `your-project-path`](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000795.htm)** in the terminal and then run your project from there.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm init -y
```

use this command, it will automatically create package.json file with all your machine information.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this identical error and terminal (foolishly, on my part) was in a parent directory instead of the correct one (where `package.json` was correctly located).

All I did in terminal was `cd [insert correct directory name here, overwriting brackets]` and that corrected the problem.

Comment: Exactly mine error... shamed :(

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I didn't have a package.json file for some reason. After I wget this file into my directory, I was able to run npm install

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/package.json

Comment: I know this is old, but I still have to say - this might suppress the specific error, but this is not the right way to deal with this problem. You're pulling down the package.json for Bootstrap, a completely different project from yours.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! 
I also tried many options for this. I am also using windows.This command helped and saved my time:

```
npm install -g npm@lts
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, try to go to the home "user@user:~$ " (cd + enter key), and npm install -g your your_module.

Answer (score 1):

just install any package you want with `-g`

`npm install -g express`

Answer (score 1):

the previous tips do not pay attention to any change for me. at the end this works for me:

1. delete the local repo folder
2. git clone https ... myRebo.git
3. npm install
4. npm start

hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

For the following command

```
sudo npm install react browserify watchify babelify --save-dev
```

I got same error

> saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/Path/package.json'

But when I run the command

```
sudo npm install -gd react browserify watchify babelify --save-dev
```

then no missing file or directory message appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have run `npm install -y` to skip the question step for creating the missing file `package.json`, `y` means yes

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue while installing typescript. I just initialized an package.josn file by the following command

```
npm init -y
```

And then i installed my typescript

```
npm install -g -typescript
```

http://blossomprogramming.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the directory or the folder in which you're installing your new package.
This happened to me as well, 
My whole project was in a subdirectory and I was trying to install in the main directory. After checking the whole thing I found out that I had to install in the subdirectory where my project files and package.json files are located and it's done.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was trying:

npm install --save-exact express@4.17.1 cors@2.8.5 express-bearer-token@2.4.0 
@okta/jwt-verifier@1.0.0 mongoose@5.6.7

which I got from: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/09/11/angular-mongodb

I had to separate the packages and run them one by one.  I think the backslash caused problem.

Answer (score -1):

Adding -g before the package name worked for me. Looking for documentation to explain why this works..

Answer (score -1):

Generate package.json without having it ask any questions. I ran the below comment in Mac and Windows under the directory that I would like to create package.json and it works

```
$ npm init -y

Wrote to C:\workspace\package.json:

{
  "name": "workspace",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "builder.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```