# npm install <package> not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, command-line, npm

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and install angular package in my project.

I have npm (4.0.5) and node (6.9.2) already installed in my system

I'm in my project folder and I run :

```
 npm install angular
```

But node_modules folder is not installed in my project directory. I've tried this command but still not working:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

The errors I got when I ran npm install angular:

```
├── angular@1.6.1 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-shim@^0.35.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY reflect-metadata@0.1.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.6.12

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open  '/Users/nilliany/package.json'
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 requires a peer of reflect-metadata@0.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.21 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN nilliany No description
npm WARN nilliany No repository field.
npm WARN nilliany No README data
npm WARN nilliany No license field.
```

Comment: do `npm init` and then try

Comment: in my project directory or globally? @RaR

Comment: In your project directory, where you want to do `npm install <package>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm can't find package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a package.json in your project to do npm install. Please do npm init from your project and follow the instructions. It will create a package.json file in your project. Later you can install any node package in your project.