# Angular CLI error during installing

Tags: command-line-interface

I have some problems during installing Angular CLI.

After `npm install -g angular/cli`

I have error as below. Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: can you verify that a package.json is in the dir ang-app2?

Comment: in dir ang-app2 there is no package.json. Which files I should copy to this dir?

Comment: have you checked out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json

Comment: @hurnhu - I have read topic mantioned by You but I didnt found solution. Do I need git instaled on my machine?