# npm installed package does't have package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm-install

when i run 'npm install', it console log these warnings:

[image]

I found that, these modules has no 'package.json' file in the dir.

so, how can i fix this npm install problem?

Comment: How do you install node_modules? C/p or npm install?

Comment: npm install ...

Comment: What is the package that you are trying to install, be more specific.

Comment: Probably something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json, did you try `npm install -d` or `$ npm install -g express`?