# Node.js Error - no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules

node.js gives me the following warning:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/myapp/package.json'

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/myapp/package.json'
```

even though the package.json file is around in that directory.
I didn't have problems with this before but today it just appeared out of nowhere.
I deleted my node_modules folder and tried to reinstall the modules but the same warning keeps popping up. Does anyone know a quick fix to this?
I'm using version 5.6.0 and my app is running in a Docker container.

Comment: are you sure package.json is copied inside docker container? .. Can you attach the DockerFile and .dockerignore file in the question? Are you running npm install inside docker?

Comment: @arunp9294 Yes, I'm running npm install inside the docker container and it always worked before. The package.json is inside the docker container, there's also a package-lock.json and I don't get how Node doesn't recognize the file...

Comment: are you using any frame work like Express , sails , hapi  or simple node js application?

Comment: I do use express but other than that just simple node js applications

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json check this kinda feels same

Answer (score 0):

In that same directory, create a file called `package.json`, and then paste this to `package.json`:

```
{}
```

your program should work now