# Can't run 'npm install' on a React-Native project

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I am currently trying to run a simulation of a pre-built React Native project on my computer but I couldn't install NPM on the project. Every time I run 'npm install' on the root file of the project, I get the following error:

link to image --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDBwp.jpg <--

project directory --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj8lB.jpg <--

You can check out the error log here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d5EPCun60hjCYOn_GMTM7upQXSDu9Tq0/view?usp=sharing

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling node and npm, but the problem still persists. I also tried updating pm2, but that doesn't work either. I do not have a very good understanding of how npm works, and honestly could not pin point where the actual problem is. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json

Comment: Since your project is missing package.json file you have to create it first. Only then ```npm install``` will work correctly.

Comment: The project itself has a package.json file in the root directory. You can check it out here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y49AsKbhIuQQOnepZe56lAOQAADQgQyO/view?usp=sharing

I think that one of the dependencies is missing a package.json file, I just don't know which one.

Comment: @timpyy try to create a brand new project (an empty project) and run it ... just to figure out if the issue is in your node and npm installation, or it's something specific to your current project ... I'd suggest that you depend on **yarn** anyway