# Module 'googleapis' is not listed as dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm-install, google-api-nodejs-client

Step 1: I try to add `googleapis` as dependency and got the error

```
$ npm install googleapis
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[home]/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[home]/package.json'
npm WARN saly No description
npm WARN saly No repository field.
npm WARN saly No README data
npm WARN saly No license field.
```

Question: Why is it looking for the file in my home directory as opposed to my project directory? Especially since I am making the call from my project directory.

Step 2: I misunderstood the error and proceeded to deploying my project and that's where I got the error

```
Module 'googleapis' is not listed as dependency in package.json
```

Step 3: I now try `npm i googleapis --save` but I still get the same errors as in steps 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm just doing exactly as here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

Comment: did you run `npm init` in your project directly to create a `package.json` file?

Comment: yeah I just did that and nothing changed. I followed suggestions as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json/37687665#37687665

Comment: In VSCode I do see a package.json file and inside it I see the dependency listed as `"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^2.2.0",
    "googleapis": "^40.0.0"
  }` So I don't know why deploy is not working

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem was due to that I forgot to cd into the `functions` directory before I tried to install the dependencies.