# Is there a way that I can clear this npm error

Tags: node.js, npm

```
$npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/gatua/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/gatua/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gatua/.npm/_logs/2020-05-22T12_23_50_208Z-debug.log
```

Comment: are you running `npm start` in the directory where you have your package.json file?

Comment: Have you [created package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you are running `npm` command outside of your project folder. If it's not the case. first, you need to create package.json file by running `npm init` command.