# Get a bunch of errors when trying to run "npm start" after running "create-react-app my-app"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, terminal

Get a bunch of errors when trying to run "npm start" after running "create-react-app my-app" in the terminal.  It seems to involve a packages.json file but I've completely uninstalled node.js and installed it again and still run into the same problem. The error:

```
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/marcel/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/marcel/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marcel/.npm/_logs/2020-07-15T01_33_47_980ZMarcelMarcels-MacBook-PrMarcels-MacBook
```

Comment: does this answer your quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484829/npm-cant-find-package-json

Comment: Oof. Yeah that's it exactly, I used this code from the comments:``$ npm install -g express```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with Express

Comment: do you open terminal in project directory. after run `create-react-app my-app` then run `cd my-app` and then `npm i`, `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the directory of your React app, which will have a `packag.json` in it, before using `npm`.

## Example

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```